# Topology In Euclidean Spaces

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Assume $A, B \subsetneq \mathrm{R}^{n}$ ($n\ge 2$ arbitrary) are bounded connected sets with disjoint connected boundaries for which $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ holds. Is it true that necessarily either $A \subsetneq B$ or $B \subsetneq A$ ensues? Please sketch a proof or give a counter-example.

If you visualize some examples of two sets each in 2- or 3-dimensional euclidean space for which these conditions hold you will get more and more convinced that my conjecture should be true but when you try to establish a rigorous proof you may be reminded of the Jordan curve theorem and its higher-dimensional generalizations which seemed to be intuitively true but were really hard to prove. If my conjecture turns out to be wrong I really wonder what a counterexample will look like. That's what attracts me with the natural topology of euclidean spaces: Some conjectures seem to be intuitively true but whether they really are can be a hard task to find out.

Comment: Looks like a homework problem.

Comment: It looks like this is also true for $n=1$.

Comment: What is the essence of remarking "Looks like a homework problem."?. Although it has not been a homework problem for me, it would not matter if were because ii is of some interest in itself. So why trying to (dis)qualify it by this comment?

Comment: @UdoZerwas - You can direct your comments to specific users. Otherwise they might not notice you said anything, having moved on to other questions.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22218/what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-directing-a-comment-to-a-specific-user and links therein.

Comment: @mr_e_man  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

One can quickly present a counter-example, provided that you mean the following with "disjoint connected boundaries": If $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A$, and analogously $\partial B$ that of $B$, then you demand $\partial A \cap \partial B = \emptyset$, but not necessarily $ \partial A \cap B = \emptyset$.

If this is the correct way to interpret your condition, then consider the following example: Equip $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the canonical orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, e_3$, and let $A$ be the unit-square in the $e_1, e_2$ plane. Now let $B$ be a copy of shrunken copy of $A$ (by any real number), and rotate it by, e.g. 90 degrees around the axis of either $e_1$ or $e_2$.

Then $A$ and $B$ have nontrivial intersection (which is a subset of the span of the axis of rotation) and disjoint, connected boundaries, but at the same time, neither is entirely contained in the other one.

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know!

Cheers!

Comment: Your understanding of my question is correct but you alleged counterexample is not: Your sets have no interior points at all (because they are subsets of planes) which means all their points are boundary points but then the boundaries are not disjoint!

Comment: My fault, I was thinking of these planes in their subspace topologies. But this is, of course, wrong. Thank you for pointing that out to me! I will modify my answer, if I come up with a better one.

Comment: BTW I expect my conjecture to be true but I cannot give a rigorous proof as yet-

Comment: Visualizing some of these situations in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I would agree. I might not have time to work on this today, but a potential approach would be to prove the contrapositive using path-connectedness of open subsets  (the interiors of $A$ and $B$) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the compactness of the closures of $A$ and $B$.

And please excuse my original answer. I am spending too much time with manifolds and varying topologies...